# How does the function argument work in R's 'combn'?

Tags: r, functional-programming, combinations

Despite reading the documentation, I'm struggling to understand how the function argument works in the `combn` utility.

I have a table with two columns of data, for each column, I want to calculate the ratio of each unique combination of data pairs in that column. Let's just focus on one column for simplicity:

```
    V1
1   342.3
2   123.5
3   472.0
4   678.3
...
14  567.2
```

I can use the following to return all the unique combinations:

```
combn(table[,1], 2)
```

but of course this just returns each pair of values. I want to divide them to get a ratio, but can't seem to figure out how to set this up.

I understand that for something like `outer`, for example, you can just provide the operator as the argument but how does this transfer to `combn`?

```
combn(table[,1], 2, FUN = "/")   
# obviously not correct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the function will receive exactly one parameter. And that parameter will be vector of the elements in that particular set. The `/` function require two separate parameters, not a single vector of values. Instead you could write

```
combn(table[,1], 2, FUN = function(x) x[1]/x[2])
```

So here we get one parameter `x` and we divide the first value by the second.

Other functions such as

```
combn(1:4, 2, FUN = sum)
```

work just fine because they expect to receive a single vector of values.